# How to get the Attribute name(when duplicate attribute) from the XML using XPATH?

Tags: xslt-2.0

Can you guys help me in the below scenario using XPATH when we have a same attribute name twice for the same node as below:

```
<wd:Worker_Type_Reference>
    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">be264fa6cb8b0175451b3a2012baaf10</wd:ID>
    <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_Type_ID">Permanent</wd:ID>
</wd:Worker_Type_Reference>
<wd:Worker_Type_Reference>
    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">be264fa6cb8b0157dffabd2212bab810</wd:ID>
    <wd:ID wd:type="Contingent_Worker_Type_ID">Vendor</wd:ID>
</wd:Worker_Type_Reference>
```

I need to get the name of the attribute i.e `Employee_Type_ID` and `Contingent_Worker_Type_ID`.  The above snippet is a part of the code, just to make it simple I copied the main code. The `wd:type` *will change* based on the type of employee - Employee or Contigent Worker. To fetch the type of employee I have the only one option to get this attribute name.

I have seen other questions with the same scenario, but the duplicate attribute scenario is not there. I tried as below:

```
wd:Worker/wd:Worker_Type_Reference/wd:ID/@*[local-name()='type']
```

With this I am getting both `WID` and the `Employee_Type_ID` OR `Contingent_Worker_Type_ID`.

No clue how I can get the second value (Employee_Type_ID OR Contingent_Worker_Type_ID) for each Worker reference.

expected result for the snippet above is:

```
Employee_Type_ID
Contingent_Worker_Type_ID
```

Comment: We need to see more context, are those `wd:Worker_Type_Reference` elements the only ones in the document? Or do you have lots of them and want to group them by the `wd:ID[wd:type="WID"]` value? Then look into any introduction grouping in XSLT 2, for instance https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info has a section with some text and some examples.

Comment: Thank you Martin for you suggestion. Yes, We have lots of them in the document. I will check the link above.